# How to build boost library with open64 compiler?

Tags: c++, boost, build-process

I would like to give AMD's open64 compiler a try, but for this I first need to build some boost libraries (current version 1.46_1) using this compiler. Unfortunately, open64 is not among the toolsets provided by the boost.build system, see e.g. [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#identify-your-toolset) or in more detail [here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html#bbv2.reference.tools.compiler.gcc).

Now, how do I get boost to build with open64? Here's what I've tried / figured out so far:

- In the subdirectory `tools/build/v2/tools` there is a bunch of .jam files that seemingly define the toolsets that can then be used via the `using` directive, e.g. `using gcc ;`. These look ugly as hell and I don't really know how I would write one for open64 (or openCC, which is the actual command).
- Since the interface to openCC is apparently quite similar to that of gcc I tried tricking bjam into using it like this:

  1. In `tools/build/v2/user-config.jam` I put
     `using gcc : 4.2.5 : /usr/local/bin/openCC : <cxxflags>"-O3" ;`.
  2. I then built bjam like `./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc` and `./bjam install --prefix=my_dir`
  3. Using the thus built bjam I tried to build the boost libraries with
     `./bootstrap.sh --with-bjam=my_dir/bin/bjam --prefix=$HOME/my_targe --with-toolset=gcc --with-libraries=regex` and subsequently `my_dir/bin/bjam`

This seems to build "something" alas with names including "gcc-4.2.5" - but, come on, this can't be the real way. Is there any "right" way to do this. Has anyone tried? Are there some toolset definitions for open64 available somewhere? Other suggestions?

Comment: have you checked the boost mailing lists?

Answer (score 2):

You can try latest CMake with [boost-cmake](https://github.com/boost-lib/boost-cmake) from github.

Also please check [ryppl](http://ryppl.org/) for instructions.

In general following steps should be sufficent:

```
CXX=/usr/local/bin/openCC cmake <path to boost-cmake folder with clone>
make
```